# How to generate PDB file for custom single strand DNA squence(46 bp)？

Tags: dna

I need to generate a pdb for ssDNA to research the interaction of DNA and proteins.
I will really appreciate if you can please guide me.
Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

[A related question on SeqAnswers](https://www.biostars.org/p/198250/) does not seem to have meaningful current answers.

However, [a question on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_convert_ct_file_to_pdb_file) points helpfully to [this RNA structural modeling server](https://rnacomposer.cs.put.poznan.pl/) (RNAComposer) that might be useful, once you create secondary structure predictions. Secondary structure is not enough to predict information needed for a PDB.

An alternative somewhat older path to a PDB for RNAs would seem to be [MC-fold and MC-sym](https://major.iric.ca/MC-Pipeline/).

Granted: most of this is for RNAs, which will have a somewhat different structure and mode of folding.

The toolkit seems a little less rich for DNA, but you can still use tools such as ViennaRNA for secondary structure prediction, and there do seem to be some [recently published tools](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9503956/) for DNA structure prediction (see also [here](https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1010501)).

There are some further DNA/RNA resources [here](https://www.nakb.org/natools.html) that may be helpful.